# Wi-Fi LED does not turn on while Wi-Fi is working

Tags: wireless-networking

I have an ASUS X550L laptop.
I have recently installed Win 7.
The Wi-Fi LED does not turn on while the Wi-Fi interface is on and working.
Why is that?

Comment: Welcome on Super User. What exactly are you trying to do? What have you tried to resolve your issue? please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1391637/edit) your question and don't respond in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your [Asus X550L](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X550LB/specifications/) laptop shipped with Windows 8.1. Its [drivers download page](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X550LB/HelpDesk_Download/) has no drivers for Windows 7. Therefore, you won't have full functionality if you use Windows 7, including the WiFi light.